# how flash memory/SSD write dta internally?

Tags: ssd, flashing

I was reading a book which says:

***a flash memory consists of a sequence of B blocks, where each block consists of P pages.Data are read and written in units of pages. A page can be written only after the entire block to which it belongs has been erased (typically, this means that all bits in the block are set to 1). However, once a block is erased, each page in the block can be written once with no further erasing.***
[image]

I'm confused wht the saying of

> "once a block is erased, each page in the block can be written once with no further erasing."

Does it mean that once we write data to a block, then this block can only be read-only from now on? because according to what the author says, if you want to write data into a page, the block containing it needs to be erased first, since the block had been erased and cannot be erased for a second time, then this block is read-only?

Comment: It says that each page in a freshly erased block can be written exactly once and a page cannot be overwritten without erasing the entire block (which is very time consuming for an SSD and can be done only a limited amount of times). Once a page in a block is written (once), they are effectively read-only until the block (including all the data contained in the pages) is erased again. This also explains why an SSD drive that is almost full is significantly slower than one where there’s ample space (unwritten pages) available.

Comment: Some NAND chips support 'partial-page programming'.  A NAND page is much larger than a 512-byte sector, e.g. there could be 4 or 8 sectors (plus spare area) per page.  So partial-page programming almost makes the NAND chip writable in sector-sized rather than page-sized operations, and allows more than one "write" per "page" before an erase.